# Python Pandas reorganize dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
Type  Label_1  Label_2  Label_3
A       1        5        3
B       3        2        1
C       2        1        2
```

I'd like to format it to look like this:

```
Type  Label_type  Value
 A      Label_1    1
 A      Label_2    5
 A      Label_3    3
 B      Label_1    2
 B      Label_2    1
```

How can I do this in the most effective way? I failed to do so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we can use [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) method:

```
In [87]: pd.melt(df, 'Type')
Out[87]:
  Type variable  value
0    A  Label_1      1
1    B  Label_1      3
2    C  Label_1      2
3    A  Label_2      5
4    B  Label_2      2
5    C  Label_2      1
6    A  Label_3      3
7    B  Label_3      1
8    C  Label_3      2
```

if the order is important:

```
In [89]: pd.melt(df, 'Type').sort_values(['Type', 'variable'])
Out[89]:
  Type variable  value
0    A  Label_1      1
3    A  Label_2      5
6    A  Label_3      3
1    B  Label_1      3
4    B  Label_2      2
7    B  Label_3      1
2    C  Label_1      2
5    C  Label_2      1
8    C  Label_3      2
```

Comment: And then sorting is necessary

Comment: this is perfect, thanks a lot! didn't know about this before :)

Comment: @Maple123, glad it helps :)

Comment: For anyone who wants to know how to do the **reverse** procedure: Search for pandas "pivot" function

Answer (score 2):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df=df.set_index('Type').stack().rename_axis(('Type','Label_type')).reset_index(name='Value')
print (df)
  Type Label_type  Value
0    A    Label_1      1
1    A    Label_2      5
2    A    Label_3      3
3    B    Label_1      3
4    B    Label_2      2
5    B    Label_3      1
6    C    Label_1      2
7    C    Label_2      1
8    C    Label_3      2
```